# project builds with ndk-build but not Android studio

Tags: android, c, android-studio, android-ndk

When I build my C/C++ library using ndk-build command from the command line, it works.

```
[armeabi] Prebuilt       : libVidyoClientApp.so <= jni/lib/
[armeabi] Install        : libVidyoClientApp.so => libs/armeabi/libVidyoClientApp.so
[armeabi] Compile thumb  : vidyoguestapi <= NCR.JNI.VidyoExports.c
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: vidyoguestapi <= Ncr.Jni.Wrapper.cpp
In file included from m:/src/projects/java/VideoPlatform/app/src/main/jni/Ncr.Jni.Wrapper.cpp:6:0:
m:/src/projects/java/VideoPlatform/app/src/main/jni/include/Ncr.Jni.Wrapper.h:13:1: warning: 'typedef' was ignored in th
is declaration [enabled by default]
 };
 ^
[armeabi] Compile++ thumb: vidyoguestapi <= NCR.Vidyo.SDK.cpp
In file included from m:/src/projects/java/VideoPlatform/app/src/main/jni/NCR.Vidyo.SDK.cpp:7:0:
m:/src/projects/java/VideoPlatform/app/src/main/jni/include/NCR.Jni.Wrapper.h:13:1: warning: 'typedef' was ignored in th
is declaration [enabled by default]
 };
 ^
[armeabi] StaticLibrary  : libstdc++.a
[armeabi] SharedLibrary  : libvidyoguestapi.so
[armeabi] Install        : libvidyoguestapi.so => libs/armeabi/libvidyoguestapi.so
```

But when I try to build my project in Android studio I get a compiler error:

```
M:\src\projects\java\VideoPlatform\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/vidyoguestapi/M_\src\projects\java\VideoPlatform\app\src\main\jni\NCR.JNI.VidyoExports.o: In function `Java_com_ncr_mobilevideo_videosdk_VidyoGuestClient_sdkLoginGuest':
M:\src\projects\java\VideoPlatform\app\src\main\jni\NCR.JNI.VidyoExports.c
Error:(50) undefined reference to `VidyoClientInitialize'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make.exe: *** [M:\src\projects\java\VideoPlatform\app\build\intermediates\ndk\debug\obj/local/arm64-v8a/libvidyoguestapi.so] Error 1
```

What is different between commandline ndk-build and Android Studio?

FYI:  I remove the line that references VidyoClientInitialize, everything builds in both the commandline and Android studio.   So it seems like something environment, but I'm not sure what to look at

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now, Android Studio creates a new Android.mk on-the-fly to compile your C/C++ sources, ignoring all your dependencies on other prebuilt libraries since he can't handle them.

A better NDK support from AS/gradle is supposed to be out really soon, but in the meantime you can deactivate it and let it integrate your native libs from `libs/(armeabi,armeabi-v7a,x86,...)` by setting this inside build.gradle:

```
android {
    sourceSets.main {
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs' //set libs as .so's location instead of jniLibs
        jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call with auto-generated Android.mk
    }
}
```